# PHP merge sort not working

Tags: php, python, mergesort

I made a merge sort in python which works fine and I've tried recreating the logic in PHP but it is not working correctly. Here is the python code:

```
def merge(array):
    if len(array) > 1:
        arrayL = []
        arrayR = []
        for i in range(int(len(array)/2)):
            arrayL.append(array[i])
        for i in range(int(len(array)/2),len(array)):
            arrayR.append(array[i])
        arrayL = merge(arrayL)
        arrayR = merge(arrayR)
        left = right = insert = 0
        while left < len(arrayL) and right < len(arrayR):
            if arrayL[left] < arrayR[right]:
                array[insert] = arrayL[left]
                left += 1
            else:
                array[insert] = arrayR[right]
                right += 1
            insert += 1
        while left < len(arrayL):
            array[insert] = arrayL[left]
            left += 1
            insert += 1
        while right < len(arrayR):
            array[insert] = arrayR[right]
            right += 1
            insert += 1
    return array
```

And this is from the shell:

```
>>> merge([23,21,5,111,32,11,7,1,45])
[1, 5, 7, 11, 21, 23, 32, 45, 111]
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
function merge($array) {
    $arrayLength = count($array);
    if ($arrayLength > 1) {
        $arrayLeft = array_slice($array, 0, $arrayLength/2);
        $arrayRight = array_slice($array, $arrayLength/2);
        $arrayLeft = merge($arrayLeft);
        $arrayRight = merge($arrayRight);
        $left = 0;
        $right = 0;
        $insert = 0;
        while ($left < count($arrayLeft) and $right < count($arrayRight)){
            if ($arrayLeft[$left] < $arrayRight[$right]) {
                $array[$insert] = $arrayLeft[$left];
                $left += 1;
            } else {
                $array[$insert] = $arrayRight[$right];
                $right += 1;
            }
            $insert += 1;
        }
        while ($left < count($arrayLeft)) {
            $array[$insert] = $arrayLeft[$left];
            $left += 1;
            $insert += 1;
        }
        while ($right < count($arrayRight)) {
            $array[$insert] = $arrayRight[$right];
            $right += 1;
            $insert += 1;
        }       
        return $array;
    }

}  

print_r(merge(array(23,21,5,111,32,11,7,1,45)));
```

And this is what it outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 [2] => 23 [3] => 21 [4] => 32 [5] => 11 [6] => 45 [7] => 45 [8] => 111 )
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return $array;` statement should be outside the `if` scope.

Comment: Thank you! I spent an hour+ trying to fix this, I can't believe I didn't notice that